# Ember app wouldn't work now

Tags: ember.js, typeerror

Just a few hours ago my ember app worked fine, but now it wouldn't.

Here's what it says in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: object_utils.createObject is not a function
>   ember.debug.js:4888 DEBUG: For more advanced debugging, install the Ember Inspector from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi

Comment: Could you add some code? To show us where the error is happening...

Comment: are you using ember-cli ? ember-data ? what version of ember are you using? what change did you make (and in what file) ?

Comment: Thanks everybody, I've figured it out